# CheckBox in two forms

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I have two forms: `form1` and `form2`.

`form1` contains `checkbox1` and `button1`. `form2` contains `textbox1`.

`Button1` when clicked initiate `form2`.

What I want is that `textbox1` in `form2` shows a string "hi" if `checkbox1` in `form1` is checked.

I did the following in `form1`:
The program tansfers to `form2` from `form1` by clicking on `button1` but how can I make the program write in `textbox1` a string. Ex: "hi"

**note**: The `checkbox1` is public

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the logic out of UI classes. UI classes such as forms are for GUI only. Forms are not supposed to interact with each other or to know each other's state. The requirement you're describing sounds like business logic, not like UI.

You probably need an object that would be referenced from both Form1 and Form2, and this object will hold the current state. Clicking the checkbox will change the state of the object, and Form2 will subscribe to an event that fires every time the state is changed, so it can change the label accordingly.

Comment: Actually you are right. I'm doing business logic. But can you describe me how to code for an object? I'm still a beginner.

Comment: @Omar Create a class that will have a property and an event, and then the GUI can set the property and can subscribe to the event. I would recommend that you read a book about C#, because designing good code requires more than what can fit into an answer on SO. Good luck!